# Aligning Data frame with missing values

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, na, lm

I'm using a data frame with many `NA` values.  While I'm able to create a linear model, I am subsequently unable to line the fitted values of the model up with the original data due to the missing values and lack of indicator column.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(MASS)
dat <- Aids2
# Add NA's 
dat[floor(runif(100, min = 1, max = nrow(dat))),3] <- NA
# Create a model
model <- lm(death ~ diag + age, data = dat)
# Different Values
length(fitted.values(model))
# 2745
nrow(dat)
# 2843
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually three solutions here:

1. pad `NA` to fitted values ourselves;
2. use `predict()` to compute fitted values;
3. drop incomplete cases ourselves and pass only complete cases to `lm()`.

**Option 1**

```
## row indicator with `NA`
id <- attr(na.omit(dat), "na.action")
fitted <- rep(NA, nrow(dat))
fitted[-id] <- model$fitted
nrow(dat)
# 2843
length(fitted)
# 2843
sum(!is.na(fitted))
# 2745
```

**Option 2**

```
## the default NA action for "predict.lm" is "na.pass"
pred <- predict(model, newdata = dat)  ## has to use "newdata = dat" here!
nrow(dat)
# 2843
length(pred)
# 2843
sum(!is.na(pred))
# 2745
```

**Option 3**

Alternatively, you might simply pass a data frame without any `NA` to `lm()`:

```
complete.dat <- na.omit(dat)
fit <- lm(death ~ diag + age, data = complete.dat)
nrow(complete.dat)
# 2745
length(fit$fitted)
# 2745
sum(!is.na(fit$fitted))
# 2745
```

In summary,

- **Option 1** does the "alignment" in a straightforward manner by padding `NA`, but I think people seldom take this approach;
- **Option 2** is really simple, but it is more computationally costly;
- **Option 3** is my favourite as it keeps all things simple.

Comment: Well, actually the simplest solution is put `na.action = na.exclude` in `lm`.

Answer (score 3):

I use a simple for loop. The fitted values have an attribute (name) of the original row they belonged to. Therefore:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$fitted.values[i]<-
    fit$fitted.values[paste(i)]
}
```

"data" is your original data frame. Fit is the object from the model (i.e. fit <- lm(y~x, data = data))

Answer (score 1):

My answer is an extension to @ithomps solution:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$fitted.values.men[i]<- ifelse(data$sex == 1, 
    fit.males$fitted.values[paste(i)], "NA")
  data$fitted.values.women[i]<- ifelse(data$sex == 0, 
    fit.females$fitted.values[paste(i)], "NA")
  data$fitted.values.combined[i]<- fit.combo$fitted.values[paste(i)]
}
```

Because in my case I ran three models: 1 for males, 1 for females, and 1 for the combined. And to make things "more" convenient: males and females are randomly distributed in my `data`. Also, I'll have missing data as input for `lm()`, so I did `fit <- lm(y~x, data = data, na.action = na.exclude)` to get NAs in my model-object (`fit`).

Hope this helps others.

(I found it pretty hard to formulate my issue/question, glad I found this post!)

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not want to change the raw data**. Try this way, it's really simple.

`names(fitted.values(model))` are data's rownames of available observations, and we can use this feature to add new column:

```r
dat[names(fitted.values(model)), "fitted.values"] <- fitted.values(model)
sum(!is.na(dat[, "fitted.values"]))
# [1] 2745
```