# Calculating MSE: why are these two ways giving different results?

Tags: r, regression, data-mining, linear-regression

I am having some doubt regarding the calculation of MSE in R.

I have tried two different ways and I am getting two different results. Wanted to know which one is the correct way of finding mse.

First:

```
model1 <- lm(data=d, x ~ y)
rmse_model1 <- mean((d - predict(model1))^2)
```

Second:

```
mean(model1$residuals^2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it indeed gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, they should give you the same result. But in the first option, you should use `d$x`. If you just use `d`, *recycling rule* in R will repeat `predict(model1)` twice (as `d` has two columns) and the computation will also involve `d$y`.

Note that it is recommended to include `na.rm = TRUE` to `mean`, and `newdata = d` to `predict` in the first option. This makes your code robust to missing values in your data. On the other hand you don't need worry about `NA` in the second option, as `lm` automatically drops `NA` cases. You may have a look at this thread for potential effect of this feature: [Aligning Data frame with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38253295/4891738).